# Creating a survey in android studio

Tags: android, survey

I am creating a survey in android studio. When doing the survey, I need to calculate the score when finished. How do I set the answers to a number. For example I have Strong Disagree = 1,Disagree = 2,neutral = 3,agree = 4,strongly agree = 5

Answer (score 0):

Where are you saving this numbers you are getting from survey? If i understand what you are asking then you simple need to save those numbers to a variable and at the end calctulate together all of the variables.

If not then please post some code and explain the problem more specificly! Show us what you have written so far so it is easier to indentify the problem.